# Split Excel into Separate CSV Files - VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have seen some questions like this one but I don't know enough about VBA to customize the code to my requirements. Basically, I have a spreadsheet with 100,000 rows and I need to split the spread sheet into files of 2,000 rows with CSV format (50 CSV files in total). However, each file must contain the "Header Row" at the top of the original spreadsheet (First Name, Last Name, Email, etc.) Can someone help me with a VBA macro to accomplish this? I forgot to put in the code I have so far:

```
Public Sub Split_2000_With_Column_Headings()

Dim inputFile As String, inputWb As Workbook
Dim lastRow As Long, row As Long, n As Long
Dim newCSV As Workbook

inputFile = "PATH GOES HERE"

Set inputWb = Workbooks.Open(inputFile)

With inputWb.Worksheets(1)
    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    Set newCSV = Workbooks.Add

    n = 0
    For row = 2 To lastRow Step 2000
        n = n + 1
        .Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy newCSV.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
        .Rows(row & ":" & row + 2000 - 1).EntireRow.Copy newCSV.Worksheets(1).Range("A2")

        'Save in same folder as input workbook with .xlsx replaced by (n).csv
        newCSV.SaveAs Filename:=Replace(inputWb.FullName, ".xlsx", "(" & n & ").csv"), FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Next
End With

newCSV.Close saveChanges:=False
inputWb.Close saveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

To me this appears as it should work but nothing happens when I run it. Any ideas? (Note: PATH GOES HERE is replaced with the path of file)

Comment: It would be good to understand what you have done so far, so can you share your current code please?

Comment: I just added it, sorry about that.

Comment: Okay, I figured out the issue. I was using the wrong format. However, now when I try to run the script it stops if there isn't something in the cell in column A. Any idea why this is?

Comment: The code works fine for me and produces the expected result, also I do not see any errors in the code. I created a Data.xlsx with 3 columns and 100,000 rows using Excel 2010. Copied the above code to a new workbook and replaced the "PATH GOES HERE" with actual path. On completion of the code I had 50 new csv files i.e., Data(1).csv through Data(50).csv with 2000 records in each with headers in place in the same folder. Not sure why its not working for you? Do you see any error message?

Comment: You are finding the lastrow based on column A `lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row`, so if column A is empty it'll obviously not enter the loop and produce nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar need and the solution of the OP worked except I did put the opening and closing of the new CSV in the loop as to not crash Excel:

```
    For row = 1 To lastRow Step 2000

        'add workbook inside the loop
        Set newCSV = Workbooks.Add

        n = n + 1

        .Rows(row & ":" & row + 2000 - 1).EntireRow.Copy newCSV.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")

        'save in same folder as input workbook with .xlsx replaced by (n).csv
        newCSV.SaveAs Filename:=Replace(inputWb.FullName, ".xlsx", "(" & n & ").csv"), FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

        'close workbook inside the loop
        newCSV.Close saveChanges:=False

    Next
```